# LowLevelKeyboardProc cannot receive 'VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE' events when an application is using SystemMediaTransportControls

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, hook, win32com

Using `SetWindowsHookEx()` to monitor keyboard input events, I noticed that if an application in the background is using `SystemMediaTransportControls` API(s) to control its media player then my hook never receives anything about `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`. Why does this happen?

I think at some point, the action doesn't get posted to the thread input queue(?) Is that some kind of OS-level control over Media Play/Pause keys? Can I bypass that behavior?

Comment: Did you try `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT That's what I meant by `LowLevelKeyboardProc`

Answer (score 0):

After my test, I can capture the `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`(0xB3,Play/Pause Media key). The following is a log produced by my program.
[image]

Comment: Now open Chrome/Chromium based browser or Spotify and play a media, you will stop receiving `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` events but other key events are fine I guess

Comment: What is **I guess**? It also works except `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` begins to control browser media after [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls) stopped.

Comment: So the thing is I would still like to listen to `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` key even a browser or an application starts using `SystemMediaTransportControls`. But I also would like to know how this `SystemMediaTransportControls` restricts other application from receiving `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` events.

Comment: There is no problem about `SystemMediaTransportControls` in my opinion.

Comment: Chrome, Spotify most of the modern application uses `SystemMediaTransportControls` blocks other application from getting any kind of media control callback. I really think `SystemMediaTransportControls` does some OS-level staff to restrict other application getting those events.

Comment: Perhaps `SystemMediaTransportControls` is in the first order to receive the event.

Comment: I tried opening my hook application first and even with administrator privilege and opened chrome after that still same result.

Comment: What‘s mean? Can't  Your hook application receive the `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` event?

Comment: If a background application isn't using `SystemMediaTransportControls` then it can't otherwise it can.

Comment: Can the `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` key control such application?

Comment: If you use `SendInput` to send the `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` key press then those applications can receive the event but my hook application doesn't.